# Error adding NSString variable into plist file

Tags: nsstring, plist

I've a problem I'm struggling with for a lot of time...please help.

I'm using the following line of code to add record to a plist file:

[data_appo setObject:@"string value" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",(i-1)]];

and it works ok. Now,if I try to read the string from the file than adding it (I need to duplicate the value with a different key) as follows

NSString *string_appo=[data_appo objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",j]];

[data_appo setObject:string_appo forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",(i-1)]];

then I gest ERROR_EXEC and the app crashes...

Any idea???

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you saved the plist file after making the addition. I do this a lot and I do it like this

```
     //find the plist file
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Notes.plist"]; 
    //set the value for the key
        [notesData setValue:textView.text forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"General notes %d",selectedIndex]];
    //save the plist file   
        [notesData writeToFile: path atomically:YES];
    //relese and reload it
        [notesData release];
        notesData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
```

I hope this helps!